# SQL max of alphanumeric substring

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I would like to create a query which returns the maximum of an alphanumeric value.
I have many VARCHAR fields which are the followings:

[image: EXO00000AA EXO00000AB EXO00000AC .... EXO00001AA]

And I would like to have the return the max of this string ("EXO00001AA" in my case).

I have already implemented this :

```
SELECT MAX(NUMERO_REFERENCE)
FROM DD02219_DECISION_EXO
```

But It doesn't take into account the numeric part ... Is there a way to take the max with alpha and numeric digits too ?
I'm in ORACLE SQL

thank you in advance

Comment: Yes it does.  It returns the maximum according to the rules of comparing strings.

Comment: Please add your DBMS

Comment: I'm in ORACLE SQL

Comment: Can you give an example of a **few strings** where this returns an incorrect answer, and which one you would expect to be returned?

Comment: If you see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cff741/1/0 the result is correct.

Comment: Complete conjecture at this point, I guess they expect the one ending '2C' here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/045df/1 to come first, need to wait and see if we get a good example input and output